# setState fires and render method gets hit, but nothing rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render, setstate

I have this screen under a DrawerNavigator:

```
class myScreen extends Component {
    state: Object;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getBeers();

        this.state = {
            is_loading: true,
            beers: null,
            beers_ds: null,
        }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps: Object, nextState: Object)
    {   
        if(!nextState.is_loading)
        {
            let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
            nextState.beers_ds = ds.cloneWithRows(nextState.beers);
        }
    }

    async getBeers()
    {

        let finalApiURL = API_BASE_URL;

        let fetchResult =  await fetch(finalApiURL) 
        let Result =  await fetchResult.json(); 

        this.setState({users: Result, is_loading: false});
    }

    render() 
    {
        if(this.state.is_loading)
        {
            return(
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 50 }}>
                    <Text>
                        Loading ...
                    </Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
        else 
        {
            let renderRow = (row) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {} }>
                        <View >
                            <Text>{row.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>ADD</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            }

            return 
            (
                <View >
                    <ListView dataSource={this.state.beers_ds} renderRow={renderRow.bind(this)} />
                </View>
            ); 
        }
    } 

} 

export default myScreen;
```

Now when I get results back from the server, I `setState()`. Then, `componentWillUpdate()` gets called, and the `else()` statement in `render()` fires.

But my screen does not change and it stays on `Loading ..`.

And sometimes I get see this error:

[image]

Can anyone help in finding why this weird behavior is occurring?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

It works when I change this:

```
return 
(
```

To this:

```
return (
```

Welcome to Javascript!

Comment: @Prakashsharma `.bind(this)` does the job of passing `row`. But why would `loading...` stay on the screen after `componentWillUpdate` and `loading` is false? Weird ..

Comment: just to be sure can you change `if(this.state.is_loading)` to `if(this.state.is_loading === true)`

Comment: what react native version you use?

Comment: what is your imports?

Comment: @bennygenel no issues with the conditional if, it works fine

Comment: @MohamedKhalil `"react-native": "0.45.1",` and i am importing ListView and FlatList from `"react-native"`

Comment: This is a bit confusing since you are saying that the statement is correct but Loading is still in screen which a bit confusing since you are setting `is_loading` to false and this means it should render the `ListView` if the statement is correct.

Comment: @bennygenel `else()` statement **gets** hit, after `is_loading` gets false, I see it, but nothing changes on the screen. Super weird..

Comment: Can you try it with taking the `renderRow` out of the render? It might be messing things up.

Comment: @bennygenel ok this is so f* weird. You know how it worked? see the new edit... f***in JavaScript :D

Comment: This solution should be another _Why?_ question here. I'm sure there is an explanation for it. There must be.

Comment: @bennygenel here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309513/weird-behavior-in-render-did-i-find-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you have the latest `react native` so `ListView` is deprecated you can use `FlatList` [(Dod)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) instead

change your code to be like this

```
renderRow = (row) => {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {} }>
          <View >
              <Text>{row.name}</Text>
              <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>ADD</Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
render() {

      return(
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 50 }}>
            {this.state.is_loading ?
              <Text>
                  Loading ...
              </Text>
              :
              <FlatList data={this.state.users} renderItem={(item) => this.renderRow(item)} />
            }
          </View>
      );
}
```

Comment: same exact behavior with FlatList, any suggestion?