# Why a newline between `return` and `(` breaks the code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, syntax, render

Based on the solution of my question: [setState fires and render method gets hit, but nothing rerenders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308796/setstate-fires-and-render-method-gets-hit-but-nothing-rerenders)

Code works if there is **NO** newline between `return` and the `(`, and fails otherwise.

Example:

this works:

```
render() 
{
        return (
            <View >
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.beers_ds} renderRow={renderRow.bind(this)} />
            </View>
        ); 
}
```

But this fails:

```
render() 
{
        return 
        (
            <View >
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.beers_ds} renderRow={renderRow.bind(this)} />
            </View>
        ); 
}
```

Why?

Comment: Post the code here, in case something changes in the other answer.

Comment: @Barmar done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Automatic Semicolon Insertion might be biting you in the butt. I believe javascript will insert a `;` at the end of a `return` statement automatically.

[Why doesn't a Javascript return statement work when the return value is on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new)

Answer (score 1):

As answered here:
[Javascript function fails to return object when there is a line-break between the return statement and the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th)

it's just a matter of JS syntax. Semicolons are automatically added and thus the compiler treats

```
return
  ( sth )
```

as

```
return;
  ( sth )
```